# Redirect php using header location and passing parameters

Tags: javascript, php, parameters, http-headers, redirect

so I'm using a redirect link for going from a landing page to an offer page, but in the middle, I want to go to a redirect page that is populated according to parameters I send, for example. my url is:

```
http://domain.com/file.php?param1={param1}&param2={param2}&param3={param3}&param4={param4}
```

and in file.php I will have the following:

```
<html><head>
     <script>
     function getURLParameter(name) {
         return decodeURI(
                (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search) || [, null])[1] || ''
            );
        }
</script>
    <script>
    var param1 = getURLParameter('param1'); 
    var param2 = getURLParameter('param2');
    var param3 = getURLParameter('param3');
    var param4 = getURLParameter('param4');

    var url = 'http://domain2.com/'+param1+'?param2='+param2+'&param3='+param3+'&param4='+param4';

    window.location.replace(url);           
  </script>
</head>
<body>

</body></html>
```

now, I have been trying to use

```
header('Location: '.$newURL);
```

but I wasn´t able to make it work like that, the thing is that I would like to be able to manage the redirection to "domain2" seamsless, as in the middle I'm losing track of some information that I would like to have.

in the normal process of tracking url (domain.com) --> to destination url (domain2.com)  there is no problem, the thing is that I need to add file.php in the middle (which is in another domain) because I have an script that needs to be executed only there.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can use usual $_GET to get the params from URL string? And then in php you can do anything you want.
Like: 
http://domain.com/file.php?param1={param1}&param2={param2}&param3={param3}&param4={param4}

in file.php:

```
$param1 = $_GET['param1'];

$param2 = $_GET['param2'];
```

and etc.
Then you can set header function with needed options
Hope that helps you

Comment: I understand, but I see that this achieves the same result of what I already have.. or am I missing something?

Comment: it seems you've missed something at domain2 URL. http://domain2.com/'+param1+'?param2='+param2+ .... Param1 should be like this ?param1=param1 ... or may be you've missed / after param1: 'http://domain2.com/'+param1+'/?param2='+param2+ .....

Comment: I don't know your target URL structure -so can't explain if you missed '/' or should set param1 as parameter of URL not as the only +param1+

Comment: no, the structure is correct, the url is made by that parameter, so is correct.

Comment: Well, if we use the url1 like this: domain1.com/file.php?param1=services , content of file.php is: $param1 = $_GET['param1'];          
$new='https://www.google.com/'.$param1;
header('location:'.$new); , then as a result we'll get the redirect from our first domain to google.com/services . It seems like  yours...and it's working.

Comment: and you can set all params like that and add an include before that line?
and that will be all done in php, right?

Comment: yes, sure. if you can explain what do you need exactly - I may try to set it up to let you check then